# Powershell null pointer exception

Tags: powershell, wmi

I've been working on and off on a project to compress and move files older than *x* days to an archival folder.  I've retrofitted the script here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Compress-Log-121e63b5 to assist me however I'm running into an issue that has proved fairly annoying.

When I run this on my machine, utilizing local directories, the script completes as expected.  However, when I pass networked file paths to the script, the `Get-WmiObject` query begins returning null results.

For example, this is a sample command line that works:

```
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -File compress_and_move_files.ps1 c:\temp\ c:\temp\compress_test\ 14
```

When I move to a UNC path, I begin getting the null-valued expression error on the WMIQuery.Compress() call

```
powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -File compress_and_move_files.ps1 \\server1\temp\ \\server1\temp\compress_test\ 14
```

This is the full error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At compress_and_move_files.ps1:14 char:23
+ If ($WMIQuery.Compress <<<< ()) {Write-Host "$FullName compressed successfull
y."-ForegroundColor Green}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Compress:String) [], RuntimeE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 2):

That script attempts to retrieve a [`CIM_DataFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387236(v=vs.85).aspx) instance - a class that isn't accessible via UNC paths in WMI.

Change the script to target the remote computer and then use the local file system path:

```
$Server   = "server1"
$WMIFile  = "C:\temp\".Replace("\", "\\")
$WMIQuery = Get-WmiObject -Computer $Server -Query "SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Name='$WMIFileName'"
```